# Browserify with twitter bootstrap

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, browserify, browserify-shim

There are many similar questions including answers here on stack overflow, but none of them have worked for me, so here I am asking you guys.  I appreciate everyone's time.

I recently started using gulp with browserify, and that works great.
I then tried to use browserify for the front-end using: Backbone and Bootstrap3.

things are appearing to work, until I try to require the js file that comes with Bootstrap.  I get an error in my chrome tools stating: jQuery is undefined.

I have attempted to shim it in, but I am very confused by the shim.  I am using jQuery 2.1.1, so I should not need to shim jQuery, but it exists in the shim now, as I was desperate and trying everything.  Here is my package.json and my main.js file:

--------------package.json------------------

```
{
  "name": "gulp-backbone",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "Gulp Backbone Bootstrap",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Rob Luton",
  "license": "ISC",


  "devDependencies": {
    "jquery": "^2.1.1",
    "backbone": "^1.1.2",
    "browserify": "^4.2.1",
    "gulp": "^3.8.6",
    "vinyl-source-stream": "^0.1.1",
    "gulp-sass": "^0.7.2",
    "gulp-connect": "^2.0.6",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.2.0",
    "browserify-shim": "^3.6.0"
  },

  "browser": {
    "bootstrap": "./node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.js",
    "jQuery": "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
  },

  "browserify": {
    "transform": ["browserify-shim"]
  },

  "browserify-shim": {
    "jquery": "global:jQuery", 
    "bootstrap": {
      "depends": [
        "jQuery"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

------------------------- main.js ----------------------

```
var shim = require('browserify-shim');
$ = require('jquery');
var Backbone = require('backbone');
Backbone.$ = $;
var bootstrap = require('bootstrap');

/* the following logs fine if I comment out the bootstrap require, otherwise I get 'jQuery undefined' */

console.log(Backbone);
$(function() {
    alert('jquery works');
});
```

Comment: You might be interested in the Bootstrap UMD scaffolding that was removed in https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/13904

Comment: see my answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24978244/using-bootstrap-3-0-with-browserify/24981030 if you don't want to use browserify-shim

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You shouldn't need to shim jquery that way if you've installed it with npm. The following works for a project I've been writing:

I've also learned that using npm for bootstrap is kind of a PITA. I've been using bower to install and maintain certain front-end components when they need to be shimmed like this.

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "...",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "...",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "..."
  },
  "browser": {
    "d3js": "./bower_components/d3/d3.min.js",
    "select2": "./bower_components/select2/select2.min.js",
    "nvd3js": "./bower_components/nvd3/nv.d3.min.js",
    "bootstrap": "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
  },
  "browserify": {
    "transform": [
      "browserify-shim",
      "hbsfy"
    ]
  },
  "browserify-shim": {
    "d3js": {
      "exports": "d3",
      "depends": [
        "jquery:$"
      ]
    },
    "bootstrap": {
      "depends": [
        "jquery:jQuery"
      ]
    },
    "select2": {
      "exports": null,
      "depends": [
        "jquery:$"
      ]
    },
    "nvd3js": {
      "exports": "nv",
      "depends": [
        "jquery:$",
        "d3js:d3"
      ]
    }
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "browserify-shim": "~3.4.1",
    "browserify": "~3.36.0",
    "coffeeify": "~0.6.0",
    "connect": "~2.14.3",
    "gulp-changed": "~0.3.0",
    "gulp-imagemin": "~0.1.5",
    "gulp-notify": "~1.2.4",
    "gulp-open": "~0.2.8",
    "gulp": "~3.6.0",
    "hbsfy": "~1.3.2",
    "vinyl-source-stream": "~0.1.1",
    "gulp-less": "~1.2.3",
    "bower": "~1.3.3",
    "cssify": "~0.5.1",
    "gulp-awspublish": "0.0.16",
    "gulp-util": "~2.2.14",
    "gulp-rename": "~1.2.0",
    "gulp-s3": "git+ssh://git@github.com/nkostelnik/gulp-s3.git",
    "gulp-clean": "~0.2.4",
    "process": "~0.7.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "backbone": "~1.1.2",
    "jquery": "~2.1.0",
    "lodash": "~2.4.1",
    "d3": "~3.4.8",
    "rickshaw": "~1.4.6",
    "datejs": "~1.0.0-beta",
    "moment": "~2.7.0"
  }
}
```

js:

```
$ = jQuery = require('jquery');
var _ = require('lodash');
var Rickshaw = require('rickshaw');
var d3 = require('d3js');
var nvd3 = require('nvd3js');
var moment = require('moment');
require('datejs');
require('select2');

var bootstrap = require('bootstrap');
console.log(bootstrap)
```

Also - one sometimes useful thing is to have browserify-shim output its diagnostics. This is what my browserify.js task looks like:

```
var browserify   = require('browserify');
var gulp         = require('gulp');
var handleErrors = require('../util/handleErrors');
var source       = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var process      = require('process');

process.env.BROWSERIFYSHIM_DIAGNOSTICS=1;

var hbsfy = require('hbsfy').configure({
  extensions: ['html']
});

gulp.task('browserify', ['images', 'less'], function(){
    return browserify({
      transform: ['hbsfy', 'cssify'],
            entries: ['./src/javascript/app.js'],
        })
        .bundle({debug: true})
        .on('error', handleErrors)
        .pipe(source('app.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/'));
});
```

Comment: Thanks much for your reply.  The question is centered around twitter bootstrap, that is what is causing the headache.  As I mentioned, I understand I shouldn't need to shim jquery, I was just trying everything I could think of to get bootstrap.js to work with browserify, and it has a dependency on jQuery.  jQuery actually works just fine in my example, but when I use the line to require 'bootstrap' I get the 'jQuery' undefined error in the console.  So I am probably shimming bootstrap in the wrong way.  I hope that is clear.  Thanks again for the reply.

Comment: Hey @rob.luton, I've updated my answer to include bootstrap. Sorry about not being more direct earlier. I hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you!  I haven't had a chance to try it yet, but the example represents exactly what I need.

Comment: cool yeah it compiled fine for me, so I hope it will work for you.

Comment: @urban_racoons I found that using `jquery:jQuery` worked for me while `jquery:$` threw an Error.[Check this note,Im using evernote because my pastebin is still blocked,sorry for the code formatting](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s218/sh/909976b1-ded8-48c6-80ac-04238b0ccb3d/8daebbd108b23d20ac6d2f300f570341) Im using Bootstrap 3.3.1

Comment: Thanks. Solved my bootstrap problem. As mentioned in one of the comments, jquery:jQuery works instead of jquery:$

Comment: @vamsiampolu Thanks for pointing that out. For whatever reason, my setup will build with either $ or jQuery, but looking at the bootstrap code I agree that it should be jQuery, so I've changed the answer. Sorry it took me so long to update the answer!

Answer (score 26):

There is error as I am using browserify which require the variable '$' or 'jQuery' to be defined.

adding the window to make it global resolve the error. Not sure if this would be the correct way to do, if not, let me know.

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
var bootstrapjs = require('bootstrap-sass');
```

Comment: This should be perfect answer! only when are using jquery npm dependency instead of bower. No need to add shim :)

Comment: It works, but still feels kinda hacky... Isn't the point of Browserify to avoid such things?

Comment: @art-solopov it is hacky but it's this or re-author a 3rd party library to make it commonjs-able.

Comment: This one line change fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

I've been wondering about this for a while. This simple solution does the job for me:

```
import foo from 'foo';
import bar from './bar';
import { default as $ } from "jquery";
global.$ = $;
global.jQuery = $; // This one does the trick for bootstrap!
// Boostrap's jQuery dependency only works with require, not with ES6 import!
const btp = require('bootstrap');
```

Comment: Now, how to include the bootstrap css dependency in a similar way without adding it directly to the html file?

Answer (score 1):

So to make `Bootstrap` to work with `Browserify` you're going to need one of [Browserify CSS transforms](https://github.com/browserify/browserify/wiki/list-of-transforms).

**First the index.js (`browserify` entry)**

```
// Bootstrap needs jQuery on the Window
window.jQuery = $  = require('jquery');
// include popper.js if you want Bootstrap tooltips
window.Popper = require('popper.js');
// include bootstrap js libs (not the CSS libs as yet)
require('bootstrap');
// then the CSS Lib
require('bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css');
```

**NPM Installs**:

```
npm install bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.6 jquery popper.js
```

**To use tooltips globally**:

*Per the Bootstrap [docs](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/tooltips/#example-enable-tooltips-everywhere).*

```
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
```

I have a Browserify-Budo repo [here](https://github.com/peterbarraud/rapo-browserify-budo-bootstrap.git). If you want to see it working.