# Error using Bootstrap & jQuery Packages in ES6 with Browserify

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6, browserify

I'm trying to use [**Bootstrap**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap) with [**jQuery**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery). I'm using [**Browserify**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/browserify) with a [**Babel**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel) transform to compile. I get the following error.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
```

I've tried importing the packages like this, but I get the above error.

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import Bootstrap from 'bootstrap';
```

Searching around, I found [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24978244/using-bootstrap-3-0-with-browserify#24981030), so I tried this but I still get the same error.

```
import $ from 'jquery';
window.$ = window.jQuery = $;
import Bootstrap from 'bootstrap';
Bootstrap.$ = $;
```

Am I importing these packages incorrectly with ES6 or is it done in a different way? The last thing I tried was importing the packages without ES6 like this, but I still got the same error.

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
var Bootstrap = require('bootstrap');
Bootstrap.$ = $
```

Comment: Why are you trying to import the files like this, any specific use case?

Comment: I'm importing them because that's how browserify works. You import packages like this and then compile them into one js file.

Comment: Are they located in the same folder as the .js file you're importing them in?

Comment: @NickKenens All my packages are inside a `node_modules` directory. I have no problem with any of the packages that are inside the `node_modules`. The problem only occurs when I try to use the `bootstrap` package.

Comment: This is getting fixed for BS4 hopefully soon, see https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/17201

Comment: your code is different from the answer you cited

Comment: @chiliNUT Only the first two are different from the answer I cited, the last example I showed in my question is the same.

Comment: @Enijar have you tried something along the lines of `var bootstrap = require("./node_modules/bootstrap...")` ?

Comment: @NickKenens No, because that wouldn't work.

Comment: @Enijar why wouldn't it work? the require('jquery') is doing the exact same just under the hood, it's also looking within the node_modules folder. So, defining the relative path is a perfectly fine option.

Comment: @chiliNUT I missed out a line in my question's code. I've edited it in.

Comment: @NickKenens Thanks for your suggestion that solved half of the problem for me. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by [**Pete TNT**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2138943/pete-tnt), there is a [**bug**](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/17201) in the Bootstrap package I am using. I switched to using [**this Bootstrap package**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap-sass) and made the following changes to my code.

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
var Bootstrap = require('bootstrap-sass');
Bootstrap.$ = $;
require('../../../../../node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap');
```

It looks like, for the time-being, ES6 `import`s will not work with `jquery` and `bootstrap` packages in the way I was trying to use them.

Comment: FYI, I got it working with the original `bootstrap` package just by using `require()` instead of `import`.

Comment: @Enijar "_It looks like, for the time-being, ES6 imports will not work with jquery and bootstrap packages"_ Is this still the case in 2016, because I cannot also import `bootstrap-saas` and its dependency `jquery` using ES6 modules syntax

Comment: this worked for me. is there a more clean way of doing it?

Answer (score 10):

The accepted answer helped me to right track but the final solution for me was a bit shorter so I will post also here.

```js
// Importing jQuery in ES6 style
import $ from "jquery";

// We need to expose jQuery as global variable
window.jQuery = window.$ = $;

// ES6 import does not work it throws error: Missing jQuery 
// using Node.js style import works without problems
require('bootstrap');
```

Comment: I like this solution totally instead of writing plugin section in webpack configuration.

Answer (score 2):

I've tried many many solutions but for some reason I had to define the global jquery in **lowercase** on the base script (eg. main.js)

```
import jQuery from 'jquery'
global.jQuery = jQuery
global.jquery = jQuery // jquery lowercase was the solution for me
global.$ = jQuery
let Bootstrap = require('bootstrap')
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
```

This solutions also works for vue-cli + jquery + bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

@Enijar's solution didn't work for me. Had to use old CDN method.

```
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"   
integrity="sha256-cCueBR6CsyA4/9szpPfrX3s49M9vUU5BgtiJj06wt/s="   
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

https://code.jquery.com/