# Adding bootstrap to Vue CLI project

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, vue.js

I'm new to Vue and webpack in general and I'm having a hard time figuring out how to import things.

I created a fresh Vue project through `vue init` I added bootstrap 4 with `yarn add bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.6`

In **main.js** I try to import bootstrap and jquery:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import jQuery from 'jquery';
import bootstrap from 'bootstrap';
import App from './App';
import router from './router';
```

But I get:

> Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery. jQuery must be
>   included before Bootstrap's JavaScript.

`window.jQuery = window.$ = $;` does *not* work

Finally, where and how do I load the Sass such that it's available to the whole app?

Comment: This might help ~ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34120250/error-using-bootstrap-jquery-packages-in-es6-with-browserify

Comment: This too ~ https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/issues/696

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error using Bootstrap & jQuery Packages in ES6 with Browserify](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34120250/error-using-bootstrap-jquery-packages-in-es6-with-browserify)

Comment: (window.$ = $; window.jQuery = $;) do not work for me.  
Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery. jQuery must be included before Bootstrap's JavaScript.

Comment: Also if I add them before the bootstrap import I get a linter error, it wants all the imports at the top.

Comment: "`window.jQuery = window.$ = $;` does not work" Well, no, because nowhere in your code is `$` being set. `window.jQuery = window.$ = require('jquery')` might work better.

Comment: This Answer may help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54755246/how-can-include-bootstrap-min-js-from-node-modules-in-vue-cli/68726801#68726801

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I was having the same issue and this is what I ended up with however, I didn't use Bootstrap alpha since the beta has since been released.

---

1. Install Bootstrap along with its dependencies, jQuery and Popper.js:

```
npm install bootstrap@4.0.0-beta popper.js jquery --save-dev
```

2. Edit your `/build/webpack.dev.conf.js` file to add a plugin for jQuery and Popper.js to deal with dependencies (you can read more about that  in the [Bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/webpack/)):

```
plugins: [
    // ...
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: 'jquery',
        jQuery: 'jquery',
        'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
        Popper: ['popper.js', 'default'],
        // In case you imported plugins individually, you must also require them here:
        Util: "exports-loader?Util!bootstrap/js/dist/util",
        Dropdown: "exports-loader?Dropdown!bootstrap/js/dist/dropdown",
        // ...
    })
    // ...
]
```

3. Edit `/src/main.js` to import Bootstrap into the app's entry point:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import router from './router'
import 'bootstrap' // ←
```

4. Edit the App.vue' file's `<style>` portion to import Bootsrap into your app's root css:

```js
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <img src="./assets/logo.png">
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'app'
}
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: 'Avenir', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}

@import'~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
</style>
```

5. Run your Vue app from the CLI

```
npm start
```

[image: Screenshot of the Vue.js project]

---

> I had to add the @import rule after the #app selector, otherwise the scoped styling
> would be canceled out by the Bootstrap import. I think there is a better way to do this so I will update my answer once I figure it out.

Comment: Looks like you can, instead of importing into the css, in your main.js file just below 

    `import 'bootstrap'`

you can add 

    `import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';`

Comment: I think that these should be installed as regular dependencies not -dev dependencies

Answer (score 47):

You don't want to do any kind of adjustment in `webpack.config.js` like adding jQuery global in plugin array.
Once you installed all `bootstrap` dependencies like `jQuery` and `popper` than just `import` them in `app.vue` or `main.js` (you can import separately in each component if you wish)

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
import 'jquery/src/jquery.js'
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js'
```

thats it ..

Comment: This should become the selected answer

Comment: This is it. What is that webpack haystack as accepted answer?

Answer (score 17):

I will try to be as precise  as possible

1.Go the the Vue Cli project
 run :

`npm i bootstrap jquery popper.js`

2.Go to `src/main.js`
import like:

`import 'bootstrap';`
`import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';`

Answer (score 11):

Only For Bootstrap 5

Follow the below in cmd

1. vue create project-name
2. Select Vue version
3. cd project-name
4. npm i bootstrap @popperjs/core (just bootstrap means latest available bootstrap version)

   ```
                 (or)
   ```

   i)npm i bootstrap (to install bootstrap)

   ii)npm install --save @popperjs/core (to install popper.js)

   **Note:** Try this if only point 4 emits error
5. Add the below to src/main.js
   import 'bootstrap';
   import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
6. Done now bootstrap will work on Vue-Cli

Answer (score 8):

With Vue CLI v3.x/v4.x, you can also use the [@techiediaries/vue-cli-plugin-bootstrap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@techiediaries/vue-cli-plugin-bootstrap) to quickly add the latest Bootstrap 4 version in your Vue project without manually adding any files or settings.

Head over to a new command-line interface, navigate to your project's folder and run the following command:

```sh
$ vue add @techiediaries/bootstrap
```

The plugin will take care of adding any configuration options and install the dependencies into your project so you can start using Bootstrap classes right away without spending time figuring out what settings or dependencies you need to add.

Answer (score 5):

For **Gridsome** users, the solution is exactly the same!

```
yarn add jquery bootstrap popper.js
```

```js
import 'jquery/src/jquery.js';
import 'popper.js/dist/popper.min.js';
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js';
```

You can also import the css here like this
`import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'` however bootstrap provides a SCSS file which can be highly customisable, if you want this kind of customisation, import in the `main.js` file a new scss file

```js
// Load core styling
import '~/assets/styles/core.scss';
```

and then import bootstrap like this

```
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
@import 'theme.scss';
```

The theme.scss follows this document https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/theming/

Answer (score 1):

Brother, Greetings!
Simple way to install and **configure Bootstrap** in your **Vue project** is that

1. First install bootstrap using a command in the terminal of the IDE which is below:

   **npm i bootstrap**
2. You need to configure this in your main.js file so that it is applied to the whole project. You need to import this from **node_modules** folder to use it in project.

   **import "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";**

   **import "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle";**

Just paste these lines in your **main.js** file because this is the path where your
required bootstrap files will be if not then check the path and edit this path.

If you want to test whether it has worked or not, go to the **app component** and
**create a button**, provide it a **bootstrap class** and run the project to see whether
it is working or not.

## Thanks, take care :)

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what packages you already have installed (such as Vuetify), you may not be able to use boostrap 4 + vue 3. Check your versions to confirm before following the directions in the thread!

Answer (score 0):

As usual in JS ecosystem the answers get out of date very quick.. this is what is working for my right now:

```bash
$ yarn add jquery bootstrap @popperjs/core
├─ @popperjs/core@2.11.5
├─ bootstrap@5.2.0
└─ jquery@3.6.0
```

```js
// main.js
import '@popperjs/core/dist/umd/popper';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
import 'jquery/src/jquery.js'
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js'
```

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple.

> Step 1: Install bootstrap

```
npm install bootstrap
```

Now inside the module, the `bootstrap` folder gets added which confirms that the installation is successful.

[image: Bootsrap installtion confirmation pic]

> Step 2: Import bootstrap into main.js folder

```
import "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle";
```

[image: You are done]

Hey  now you can see that Bootstrap is added. And add some bootstrap colors for testing.

[image: boostrap added output on side]

Answer (score -2):

use [Bootstrap](https://www.bootstrapcdn.com) CDN and include it as a  in your index.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

I never used Bootsrap with Vue.js, as I'm not a fan. But when I used Bulma's sass, first I did `npm install` for Bulma. Then I created a folder in `src/assets/sass`  and inside it created a `main.scss` and inside it I imported bulma by `@import '~bulma/bulma';`

Comment: This doesn't allow for usage of any of the jQuery functionality.
It should be installed the way specified in the accepted answer

Answer (score -2):

jQuery is not required in current version (Right now: "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "bootstrap-vue": "^2.5.0")

- install bootstrap

  - `npm install bootstrap-vue bootstrap --save`
- Then, register BootstrapVue in your app entry point (main.js)

  - `import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.esm';`
  - `Vue.use(BootstrapVue)`
- And import Bootstrap and BootstrapVue css files in main.js:

  - `import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'`
  - `import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'`

Comment: jQuery is required in bootstrap 4. However, the current bootstrap version 5.0.0.beta3 and future versions will not require jQuery. Your first sentence gave a false impression that jQuery is not a dependency for bootstrap 4.