# how can Include bootstrap.min.js from node modules in vue cli

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

i'm using vue cli . I have installed bootstrap using `npm install bootstrap` command. i have successfully imported `@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" ;` on vue component but when i include script `<script src="../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>` on index.html before closing body tag its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import the bootstrap js file just in main.js just like you did with the css file. So add `import 'bootstrap'` to the main.js.

Comment: unable to add @import "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"; on main .js  please share real example

Comment: How did you setup your project, did you use vue cli?

Comment: yes everything is default vue cli  i have  app.vue and component folder by default .  in addition i have just install bootstrap using `npm install bootstrap` . but do not know how to add bootstrap.min.js

Comment: Take a look at this article: https://travishorn.com/adding-bootstrap-to-a-vue-cli-project-98c2a30e0ed0

Comment: i am still not find solution. but give you point . if found comment me

Answer (score 0):

**Install bootstrap** using **[npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap)**

```
npm install bootstrap
```

Edit **src/main.js** file of your app. Import like this.

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js'
```