# Bootstrap-Vue is Not Added

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

**Main.JS**

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import 'bootstrap'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' 

//createApp(App).mount('#app')


import CoreuiVue from '@coreui/vue'
import CIcon from '@coreui/icons-vue'
import { iconsSet as icons } from '@/assets/icons'

const app = createApp(App)
app.use(CoreuiVue)
app.provide('icons', icons)
app.component('CIcon', CIcon)
app.mount('#app')
```

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <PermissionRequestPage msg="Welcome to Your Vue.js App"/>
</template>

<script>
import PermissionRequestPage from './components/PermissionRequestPage.vue'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    PermissionRequestPage
  }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss">
// Import Main styles for this application
@import 'styles/style';
</style>
```

[Code Used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rb8sY.png)

[Using Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHgM4.png)

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHhdx.png)

I tried this link but nothing changed.
[Adding bootstrap to Vue CLI project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42684661/adding-bootstrap-to-vue-cli-project)

Comment: You use this package https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs?
If it's the case, have you installed it, with npm or yarn.

Comment: YES,

"dependencies": {
    "@coreui/bootstrap-vue": "^1.0.0-beta.0",
    "@coreui/chartjs": "^3.0.0",
    "@coreui/coreui": "^4.2.3",
    "@coreui/icons": "^2.1.0",
    "@coreui/icons-vue": "2.0.0",
    "@coreui/utils": "^1.3.1",
    "@coreui/vue": "^4.5.0",
    "@coreui/vue-chartjs": "2.0.1",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.6",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.3",
    "bootstrap-vue": "^2.23.1",
    "core-js": "^3.26.1",
    "jquery": "^3.6.4",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "vue": "^3.2.47",
    "vue-router": "^4.1.6",
    "vuex": "^4.1.0"
  },

Comment: I see you use vue3, try to remove from dependencies your installation of bootstrap and do exactly this https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs#vue-cli-3 (skip the first line for creation of project)

Comment: Is this what you mean by the first line in the setup;
https://i.hizliresim.com/d3p1g0e.png
Or
is it ?
npm install bootstrap-vue

Comment: Yes i say, not used this line ```npx @vue/cli create my-project```, because it's for start a new vue (cli) project, and you already have one :)

Comment: I understood very differently. Thx.