# Is there any way to import CSS libraries via browserify

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, bower, browserify

I wonder is there any way to import CSS libraries like `twitter-bootstrap` via `browserify`?

I like the way how `browserify` works, so I don't want to switch to `bower` just for CSS files.

How is it usually handled anyway?

Answer (score 0):

[Using Bootstrap 3.0 with Browserify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24978244/using-bootstrap-3-0-with-browserify)

Probably this is one good topic for you. Hope you can find answers there.

Comment: I think I've found the better option -- https://www.npmjs.com/package/browserify-css